# Correct use of the pronoun reference

Tags: pronouns, reference

Is this the correct use of the pronoun reference "**this**". Were you able to tell what the pronoun **this** is referring to?

Based on the feedback received, my strengths were having strong arguments as well as good transitions and use of quotes. My essay discussed the strategies adopted by Apple in making their products more desirable and how they evolved as their product line also changed. I was able to tie **this** to the ideas introduced by Jib Fowles on the effective use of appeals in marketing.

Comment: The referent is unclear.

Comment: Since *this* is singular, it must either be Apple's product line or your essay. Neither choice appears to be what you actually want to say. (I believe that "the feedback received" is too far away to be "this".)

Comment: It sounds like the "strategies" and "how they evolved" are all being roped in under "this", such that you probably mean something like "this analysis".

Comment: Don't make us guess; just add the noun you know it to refer to: *this* ***feedback***, *this* ***discussion***, *this* ***product evolution***, or whatever else it is that you know it to be.